# having issues using gl_VertexID to draw const vertices that are inside the shader

Tags: c++, opengl

hi there am having problems with gl_VertexID it seems to be not updating or something when i use it in OpenGL program to draw vertices that are stored in the shader as vec4's,as far as i know this should be fairly straightforward and do the job without any problems or issues as i have done everything correctly but unfortunately it isnt showing anything

here is :

my main program

```
#include "shaders.h"

int main(){

glfwInit();

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", NULL, NULL);        
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
glewInit();


//Create Vertex Array Object
//vertex array object holds the state 
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

//compile and link shaders here

GLuint program = compile_shaders();
glUseProgram(program);

while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();

    // Clear the screen to black
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Draw a triangle from the constant values in shader
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glFlush();
 }


}
```

now the problem is that when i run the program i am trying to draw from the vertices that are in the shader, and when i run the program all i get is a blank screen and nothing get drawn

here are the shades and shaders.cpp it is:

```
#include "shaders.h"

GLuint compile_shaders(void){
   GLuint vertex_shader;
   GLuint fragment_shader;
   GLuint program;

const GLchar * vertex_shader_source = {    
   "#version 430 core\n"
   "void main(void)\n"
   "{\n"
   "const vec4 vertices[3] = vec4[3](vec4( 0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),\n"
                                    "vec4(-0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0),\n"
                                    "vec4( 0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0));\n"
   "gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID];\n"
   "}\n"
};

 const GLchar * fragment_shader_source = {  
    "#version 430 core\n"
    "out vec4 color\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "color = vec4(0.0,0.8,1.0,1.0)\n"
    "}\n"
};


 vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
 glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1 , &vertex_shader_source, NULL);
 glCompileShader(vertex_shader);

 fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
 glShaderSource(fragment_shader, 1, &fragment_shader_source, NULL);
 glCompileShader(fragment_shader);

 program = glCreateProgram();
 glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
 glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader);
 glLinkProgram(program);

 glDeleteShader(vertex_shader);
 glDeleteShader(fragment_shader);

 return program;
};
```

this is the shader.h file in case you need it

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

GLuint compile_shaders(void);
```

Comment: check the info log after compilation and linking

Comment: any idea what could be wrong? the shaders are very straightforward if i supplied the vertices through a buffer it works just fine, its only when i use gl_VertexID that nothing shows up

Comment: As @ratchetfreak says, you really do need to check the result of your shader compilations. For example, there are a couple of semicolons missing in the fragment shader. I don't believe that the same shader will work when you get vertices from a buffer.

Comment: i must have missed them when i wrote out the shaders here, but in my files they are not missing and i did test the shaders by giving buffer input and it rendered a triangle fine , its just that when i try to do it using this way it doesnt work and i need it to work this way

Comment: okay i checked the compile log and man was it something stupid , i was missing some semi colon